# Message is Not a JMSTextMessage error in MobileFirst 7.0 JMS Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am sending JMS message to HornetQ and consuming this message from MobileFirst 7.0 adapter. Following is my producer code:

```
    public void sendObjectMessage(Serializable object){

        Connection con = null;
        Session session = null;
        MessageProducer producer = null;
        try{
            con = this.template.getJmsDataSource().getConnection();
            session = this.template.getSession(con);
            producer = this.template.getMessageProducer(session);
            ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage();
            message.setObject(object);
            producer.send(message);
        }catch(JMSException ex){
            BaseRunTimeException.wrapAndThrow(ex);
        }finally{
            JmsUtils.closeMessageProducer(producer);
            JmsUtils.closeSession(session);
            JmsUtils.closeConnection(con);
        }
    }
```

When I am trying to consume the message using MF adapter it is throwing me below message:

```
"Runtime: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.worklight.adapters.jms.NotJMSTextMessageException: Message is Not a JMSTextMessage: HornetQMessage[ID:0db1cb4e-8d4a-11e5-a8d1-0f826151395f]:PERSISTENT"
```

My question is, is there any way through which I can consume custom serializable  classes sent by my application in MF JMS adapter? Are only `JMSTextMessage` supported by MF adapter?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the MFP server supports only javax.jms.TextMessage or derived classes for reading messages.